# css and scss - what happens if you update the css manually without using scss

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Apologies if the following doesn't make sense, I'm still trying to learn how scss and css works.

Lets say I have 2 developers.

Developer 1 manually adds bits to the css file. Developer 2 picks up the project and uses scss to add bits to the css file. Would Developer 1's work disappear? I'm guessing that when Developer 2 compiles the css file it overwrites anything which is not in the scss file?

Again, apologies if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Developer 1 is doing it wrong. No work should be done in generated files. (Nor should they really be version-controlled or anything else, but sometimes they are just for lazy convenience.)

Comment: Developer 1 is indeed doing it wrong however I wasn't aware until now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it. And the changes i made to the css file got overwritten when i compiled my scss. So yes, compiling your scss file overwrites the changes to css.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing that when Developer 2 compiles the css file it overwrites anything which is not in the scss file

Correct.

Any changes to .scss files will generate a new .css file, eliminating any changes made to it.

Note that it will change only the file the project is setup to compile to; Changes to other .css file won't be effected.

For example:

main .scss entry: styles.scss

generated .css: styles.css